# Further process a field using serde_json

Tags: rust, serde

I'm using `serde_json` to decode push messages from GCP pub/sub.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct PushMessage {
    pub message: Message,
    pub subscription: String,
}
```

In the messages, the payload is a base64-encoded string under the `data` key:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Message {
    message_id: String,
    #[serde(with = "base64data")]
    pub data: String,
}
```

… that I decode using a simple `base64data` module:

```rust
// A serializer/deserializer for base64-encoded data
mod base64data {
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
    use serde::{Deserializer, Serializer};

    use base64::engine::general_purpose::STANDARD as base64;
    use base64::engine::Engine as _;

    pub fn serialize<S: Serializer>(v: &str, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let b64 = base64.encode(v);
        String::serialize(&b64, s)
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<String, D::Error> {
        let b64 = String::deserialize(d)?;
        base64
            .decode(&b64)
            .map(|v| String::from_utf8(v).expect("Invalid UTF-8"))
            .map_err(|e| serde::de::Error::custom(e))
    }
}
```

However, I know the type I'm expecting to receive is also serialized as JSON (i.e., the base64-encoded string decodes to a JSON string), so ideally I would like to tell `serde_json` to keep processing the field, not just to decode the base64 data. Is this possible (e.g. by passing a generic parameter for the type we want to deserialize to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is problematic to inject it into the same JSON processing pipeline, because (a) not every serializer/deserializer is `serde_json`, and you need to be compatible with all of them, and (b) serde_json also allows writing to and reading from streams, not just strings.

Instead, just serialize/deserialize it inside the methods using `serde_json`:

```rust
// A serializer/deserializer for base64-encoded data
mod json_base64data {
    use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
    use serde::{Deserializer, Serializer};

    use base64::engine::general_purpose::STANDARD as base64;
    use base64::engine::Engine as _;

    pub fn serialize<T: ?Sized + Serialize, S: Serializer>(v: &T, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        let v = match serde_json::to_string(v) {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => return Err(serde::ser::Error::custom(e)),
        };
        let b64 = base64.encode(v);
        String::serialize(&b64, s)
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, T: DeserializeOwned, D: Deserializer<'de>>(
        d: D,
    ) -> Result<T, D::Error> {
        let b64 = String::deserialize(d)?;
        match base64.decode(&b64) {
            Ok(v) => match serde_json::from_slice(&v) {
                Ok(v) => Ok(v),
                Err(e) => Err(serde::de::Error::custom(e)),
            },
            Err(e) => Err(serde::de::Error::custom(e)),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting! Thanks. Should I then be able to change the structs to take a generic param, i.e. `pub struct PushMessage<T>` and `struct Message<T>` and then have the `data` field be `pub data: T`?

Comment: To answer my own question: Yes, by adding `#[serde(bound = "T: DeserializeOwned + Serialize")]` in addition to `#[serde(with = "json_base64data")]`, one can pass a generic `T` to `Message`.